# HTML validation message not showing in IE

Tags: c#, html, .net, internet-explorer, razor

I have the following code and it works well in all browsers and shows the error message when the user tries to submit the form without entering the field names.

```
<div class="row medium left">
    @Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.FirstName, new { @class = "field blink medium required", @title = "First Name*" })
    <div class="error-msg">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row medium left last">
    @Html.TextBox("LastName", Model.LastName, new { @class = "field blink medium required", @title = "Last Name*" })
    <div class="error-msg">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation message is working in all browsers except for IE. What is wrong, what fault may I have overlooked?

The rendered HTML in IE:

```
<input name="FirstName" title="First Name*" class="field blink medium required error" id="FirstName" type="text" value="First Name*" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." data-val-length-min="3" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length="Minimum of 3 characters." data-val="true" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF">

<div class="error-msg">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-     for="FirstName"></span></div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE is it not working in?  Can you show us the rendered HTML?

Comment: If you inspect the element, is it rendered on the page? Do you have any console errors? I would also validate your styling is correct.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it is working in all other browsers except for IE. All versions of IE